# Is there any single observer hook for all Admin events?

Tags: admin, event-observer, adminhtml

Am creating a module for listing the online admin users, for that i need to update a last_activity_time (custom field of admin user).On each activity of admin user current time will be updated on last_activity_time column. I am planing to consider the users who's last_activity_time is with in few minutes from current time(say 5 minutes). Is there any observer hook available for listening to all activities of admin user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](https://github.com/brentwpeterson/magento-admin-logger/blob/master/app/code/community/Strategery/Logger/etc/config.xml), you should be able to use `controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml` for your module.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `adminhtml_controller_action_predispatch_start` event for all page request.

Refer this [file](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php#l159)

All admin controller files are extends form `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action` class. So here you can hook predispatch event for all admin request.